# 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'bot' nextcord menus

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

im using https://replit.com/ to build a discord bot for a friend, everything was going ok until i ran the command and it gave me this error, i have know idea what this means or how to fix it, can anyone help?

error:

```
Ignoring exception in command <nextcord.application_command.SlashApplicationCommand object at 0x7f4bc8784df0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/nextcord/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 824, in invoke_callback_with_hooks
    await self(interaction, *args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 37, in delete_things
    confirm = await Confirm('Delete everything?').prompt(ctx)
  File "main.py", line 26, in prompt
    await self.start(ctx, wait=True)
  File "/home/runner/nextcord/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/ext/menus/menus.py", line 684, in start
    self.bot = ctx.bot
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'bot'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'bot'
```

you can see the code here https://replit.com/join/qcbhddmqnn-hamishmcd

Comment: The code you provide is completely different from the error.

Comment: Thats why im confused

Comment: try replacing `bot = commands.Bot(status=nc.Status.online)` to `bot = nextcord.Bot(status=nc.Status.online)`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'nextcord' has no attribute 'commands'

Comment: Which documentation says that `Interaction.bot` exists? Also, please provide a [mcve]. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the interaction to the interaction kwarg.

Slash commands give you a type called `Interaction`, not `Context`, so you should not be calling it `ctx`.

See this example: https://menus.docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/menus/menu_examples/#slash-commands

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def slash_menu(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await MySlashButtonMenu().start(interaction=interaction)
```

Note that in start, the slash command interaction is passed to the function as a keyword argument.

In your case, you would need prompt to take an interaction and use `self.interaction` to send the message instead of ctx or channel.

```
async def send_initial_message(self, ctx, channel):
    await self.interaction.response.send_message(self.msg, view=self)
    return await self.interaction.original_message()

...

async def prompt(self, interaction):
    await self.start(interaction=interaction, wait=True)
    return self.result

...

@bot.slash_command()
async def delete_things(interaction):
    confirm = await Confirm('Delete everything?').prompt(interaction)
    if confirm:
        await interaction.send('deleted...')
```

I'd recommend reading the docs linked above to understand the differences.